# iOS app allows me to remove a vote on a locked post

Tags: bug, status-declined, ios-app, locked, locked-votes

Steps to reproduce:

1. Vote on a post and wait until the 5 minute grace period has expired.
2. Open the post on the iOS app after it has been locked.
3. Tap the up or down vote icon you used for your original vote.

Expected behavior:

Nothing, as votes cannot be undone after the grace period as well as on locked posts.  Actually, the post had been edited since my last vote, which might have been why I had the ability to change my vote.  Ether way, I probably shouldn't have been able to.

Actual behavior:

My vote was withdrawn from the post.

Reproduced on [Time to take a stand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342440/2415822) on Meta Stack Overflow.

- App Version: 1.6.3.6
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Comment: @ShadowWizard, read my question.  The dupe you linked to has nothing to do with locked posts.  I know how vote locking works.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That doesn't make sense.  Locked posts allow you to remove a vote but not add a new one?

Comment: I thought you meant locked from voting after the 5 minutes passed. Well, it shouldn't be possible indeed.

Comment: Was just about to post a bug report. Reproduced on iOS 10.2.1, iPhone 6s, App version **1.6.2.5**, on the same post but my vote seems to have stayed (the score remain unchanged IIRC) but the indication of the vote gone (the coloring of the arrow).

Comment: @AndrewLi Can you verify on the web that your vote was actually removed?  I believe mine actually was.

Comment: @JAL After accidentally un-voting I went to web and it showed the vote count and it remained the same but the vote arrow was not colored, so the same as the app.

Comment: Status declined since the iOS app is no longer around.